# Python: "inner join" array of dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm currently using this code to compare and make a new array when the value of the key 'time' is the same for both list1 and list2:

```
def innerJoin(self, list1, list2):

    mergedList = []
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        for j in range(len(list2)):
            if (list1[i]['time']==list2[j]['time']):
                mergedList.append(list2[j])

    return mergedList
```

But when both list has, for exemple, more than 6000 items each, it's taking too long to process. There is a way to make it faster?

Can I use Numpy to improve the speed in this case?

**EDIT**

An exemple:

```
list1 =[{
      'time': '2017-07-03T01:12:13Z',
      'tag': 'TEMP',
      'value': 34.5
    },{
      'time': '2017-07-03T01:12:17Z',
      'tag': 'TEMP',
      'value': 34
    }]

list2 =[{
      'time': '2017-07-03T01:12:13Z',
      'tag': 'VOLUME',
      'value': 3
    }]
```

It should return:

```
mergedList =[{
          'time': '2017-07-03T01:12:13Z',
          'tag': 'VOLUME',
          'value': 3
        }]
```

I don't need the 'tag' and 'code', so if returns like this will be fine:

```
mergedList =[{
          'time': '2017-07-03T01:12:13Z'
        }]
```

Comment: Its always good to provide an example

Comment: What type are the values of `list1[i]['time']` and `list1[i]['time']`?

Comment: Can you assume anything about list1 and list2? Like that they are sorted for instance.

Comment: @jdehesa the list1 content is something like this: 

list1 = [{
  'time': '2017-07-03T01:12:13Z',
  'tag': 'TEMP',
  'value': 34.5
}]

- list2 has the same structure

Comment: @klutt they are order by time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something along these lines:

```
def innerJoin(list1, list2):
    set1 = set(l['time'] for l in list1)
    return [l for l in list2 if l['time'] in set1]
```

Or you could use filter:

```
    ...
    return filter(lambda i: i['time'] in set1, list2)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this. It is MUCH faster:

```
def innerJoin(list1, list2):
    mergedList = []
    # Of course you can skip the sorting if you know that they are sorted
    # but it is much faster even if you sort first
    l1 = sorted(list1, key=lambda s:s['time'])
    l2 = sorted(list2, key=lambda s:s['time'])

    i1=0
    i2=0

    while(i1 < len(l1) and i2 < len(l2)):

        if (l1[i1]['time']==l2[i2]['time']):
                mergedList.append(l2[i2])
                i1=i1+1
                i2=i2+1

        else:
            if (l1[i1]['time']<l2[i2]['time']):
                i1=i1+1
            else:
                i2=i2+1
    return mergedList
```

Your algorithm is O(n²), while my algorithm is O(n). The sorting is probably O(n*log n). The solution from knipknap is in general better to use, but I'll think this answer gives a good insight in how wise chosen algorithms can affect performance.

I tried this with n=3,000,000. When I had to sort the list, it took 10 seconds, and if I presorted it it took 3.2s.

I want to point out that your code may have a bug, depending if you want to consider it a bug or not. If there is a doublet in one of the lists, you will get doublets in the list you return. I don't know if you have a thought behind this, but that's how it is. It took me about en hour to realize that it was nothing wrong with my code. :)

If you want to use my code and DO want that feature, you'll have to modify it.